# Why would an executable say it doesn't exist when I try to run it?

Tags: linux, command-line, ubuntu

I have a compiled program, a tagger to identify parts of text, which claims it does not exist.

When I attempt to run it via the command line, I get this:

```
user@place:/home/user/explicitRedactedPath$ ls tagger
tagger
user@place:/home/user/explicitRedactedPath$ ./tagger arg and other args
-bash: ./tagger: No such file or directory
```

This executable has to be called by a generated script, which is how I ran into this issue. What are the reasons this error could show up? I'm out of ideas on how to fix it.

Notes:

- OS is Ubuntu
- The executable was copied from another machine
- The file does have execution privileges (it gives a proper not-allowed message without them)
- I've tried copying the file to a different location (same problem)
- I've tried replacing the file with a fresh copy (same problem)
- The file does exist. Opening it with pico shows a file with binary data.

Comment: Probably better asked on http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com

Comment: Try `ls -l ./tagger`

Comment: do `ldd ./tagger`

Comment: @MarkRansom ls -ld ./tagger return -rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 28938 2010-09-28 15:56 ./tagger

Comment: @nos ldd ./tagger prints "not a dynamic executable"

Comment: @Strilanc Either 'tagger' is a symlink to something that doesn't exist, Or  you've created that executable on an old system, and your other system can no longer identify that format, or the exe is a statically linked program intended for another architecture. Run `` ls -l ./tagger` and `file ./tagger` to learn more about the file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The program was compiled for an incompatible architecture, resulting in a non-executable program. The error message stating "does not exist" instead of "invalid executable" is just a very misleading message.

Recompiling it on the target machine fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I had a problem very similar to the OP (`./lfm: Command not found.` when I was looking right at it), and some of the answers here helped me figure out how to **run my executable on a different system without recompiling**.  Here's how I would advise my past self (if I thought past-me was smart enough to listen for a change):

1) Verify that the file isn't a broken link, that it has executable permissions, and that you aren't trying to run a 64-bit executable on a 32-bit OS (for me, `file lfm` returned `lfm: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped` so it is 64-bit; check the output of `uname -a` for `x86_64` in it, to verify the OS is 64-bit, too; `i386` or `i686` means 32-bit) (substitute your program name for `lfm` in these examples, of course).

2) `ldd lfm` returned the odd `not a dynamic executable` message (rather than printing the shared library dependencies), so try `readelf -l ./lfm | grep ld-linux` to find out where the executable expects to find ld-linux, which is the linux loader for dynamically linked libraries (in my case, this returned `[Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]`).

3) Checking the directory indicated by the previous command shows that the indicated ld-linux file is not there; copy it over from the machine the program was originally compiled on (or a similar system, if necessary) to that directory.

4) Try running the original program again.  (Worked for me.)  Also, `ldd ./lfm` should work now (but you can always use `readelf -d ./lfm` to see what libraries are needed, and then verify that they're available.)

Comment: This is great advice. If you're using Ubuntu, you can do a package content search at http://packages.ubuntu.com/ to find out the package and architecture which contains the required file, and then install the package. In my case, I needed the 32-bit ld-linux which I installed with `sudo apt-get install libc6:i386`

Answer (score 1):

Probably tagger is a soft-link and the target of the link isn't there. Reproduce like this:

```
$ cp /usr/bin/ld .
$ ln -s ld fff
$ rm ld
$ ./fff
zsh: no such file or directory: ./fff
```

Comment: The command "pico tagger" opens up a file (looks like binary data), so it can't be a stale soft link. Edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: @Strilanc, the `file` command is better for this than a text editor.  In the above example the output of `file fff` would have been `fff: broken symbolic link to 'ld'`

Comment: file tagger gives "tagger: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.0.0, not stripped". This is surprising, because ldd says it is not a dynamic executable. At this point I believe it's a mismatched-architecture thing and I should recompile on the target machine.

Comment: ldd says it's not an dynamic linked executable because the executable is compiled on a *very* old machine, using a different dynamic linker than the system you're trying to run it on. i.e. the real error is /lib/ld-linux.so.1  (or some other version you don't have) cannot be found.

Comment: @Strilanc: If you are on an x86_64 machine, then that's the answer. It's a rather misleading bit of output...

Comment: @nos : I had a similar problem on Ubuntu 11.10, an old program stopped running, with the same ldd (".. not an executable") and file ("ELF 32-bit ....") outputs.  Your hint about /lib/ld-linux.so.* lead me to this hack: as root  cd /lib ; ln -s ../lib32/ld-linux.so.2   .. yes, a hack indeed

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing shared libraries.

Do 'ldd tagger' to see a list of required libraries.

```
% ldd /bin/zsh                                                                                   
libcap.so.2 => /lib/libcap.so.2 (0x00007f50ce8db000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f50ce6d7000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f50ce201000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f50cdea0000)
libattr.so.1 => /lib/libattr.so.1 (0x00007f50cdc9b000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f50ceaf8000)
```

If one of them is missing it will not have a path next to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't recompile, you might consider using [statifier](http://www.linux.com/archive/articles/150677) to map a dynamic executable into a statically linked one.  Note, I haven't personally tried it.