# can't execute symbolic links to exes unless in the directory where the links are located

Tags: symbolic-link

I created symbolic links to the exe files in a bin directory using these bash scripts:

```
dan@Linux-Desktop:~/dev/arm/gcc-4.0.1-glibc-2.3.5/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/bin$ cat do_links.sh
./make_links.sh as
./make_links.sh nm
./make_links.sh ar
./make_links.sh ranlib
./make_links.sh strip
./make_links.sh objdump
./make_links.sh ld
./make_links.sh gcov
./make_links.sh gcc-4.0.1
./make_links.sh gcc
./make_links.sh gprof
./make_links.sh gccbug
./make_links.sh g++
./make_links.sh c++
./make_links.sh strings
./make_links.sh c++filt
./make_links.sh size
./make_links.sh cpp
./make_links.sh readelf
./make_links.sh addr2line
./make_links.sh objcopy
dan@Linux-Desktop:~/dev/arm/gcc-4.0.1-glibc-2.3.5/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/bin$ cat make_links.sh
ln -s arm-unknown-linux-gnu-$1 $1
```

then I ran ./do_links.sh in the bin directory and this is what the bin directory looks like:

```
dan@Linux-Desktop:~/dev/arm/gcc-4.0.1-glibc-2.3.5/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/bin$ lt
total 26552
-rwxr-xr-x 2 dan dan 2566199 May 30 16:44 arm-unknown-linux-gnu-as
-rwxr-xr-x 2 dan dan 1762396 May 30 16:44 arm-unknown-linux-gnu-nm
-rwxr-xr-x 2 dan dan 1706104 May 30 16:44 arm-unknown-linux-gnu-ar
-rwxr-xr-x 2 dan dan 1706099 May 30 16:44 arm-unknown-linux-gnu-ranlib
-rwxr-xr-x 2 dan dan 2203025 May 30 16:44 arm-unknown-linux-gnu-strip
-rwxr-xr-x 2 dan dan 2346625 May 30 16:44 arm-unknown-linux-gnu-objdump
-rwxr-xr-x 2 dan dan 2471491 May 30 16:44 arm-unknown-linux-gnu-ld
-rwxr-xr-x 1 dan dan   67493 May 30 16:44 arm-unknown-linux-gnu-gcov
-rwxr-xr-x 2 dan dan  201417 May 30 16:44 arm-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-4.0.1
-rwxr-xr-x 2 dan dan  201417 May 30 16:44 arm-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 dan dan 2013095 May 30 16:44 arm-unknown-linux-gnu-gprof
-rwxr-xr-x 1 dan dan   16196 May 30 16:44 arm-unknown-linux-gnu-gccbug
-rwxr-xr-x 2 dan dan  206621 May 30 16:44 arm-unknown-linux-gnu-g++
-rwxr-xr-x 2 dan dan  206621 May 30 16:44 arm-unknown-linux-gnu-c++
-rwxr-xr-x 1 dan dan 1602788 May 30 16:44 arm-unknown-linux-gnu-strings
-rwxr-xr-x 1 dan dan 1692490 May 30 16:44 arm-unknown-linux-gnu-c++filt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dan dan   12281 May 30 16:44 fix-embedded-paths
-rwxr-xr-x 1 dan dan 1620406 May 30 16:44 arm-unknown-linux-gnu-size
-rwxr-xr-x 1 dan dan  202864 May 30 16:44 arm-unknown-linux-gnu-cpp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 dan dan  398151 May 30 16:44 arm-unknown-linux-gnu-readelf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 dan dan 1727820 May 30 16:44 arm-unknown-linux-gnu-addr2line
-rwxr-xr-x 1 dan dan 2203026 May 30 16:44 arm-unknown-linux-gnu-objcopy
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dan dan     339 May 30 18:31 check_ver.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dan dan     460 May 30 19:09 do_links.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 dan dan     129 May 30 19:13 make_links.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dan dan      24 May 30 19:38 as -> arm-unknown-linux-gnu-as
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dan dan      24 May 30 19:38 nm -> arm-unknown-linux-gnu-nm
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dan dan      28 May 30 19:38 ranlib -> arm-unknown-linux-gnu-ranlib
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dan dan      24 May 30 19:38 ar -> arm-unknown-linux-gnu-ar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dan dan      27 May 30 19:38 strip -> arm-unknown-linux-gnu-strip
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dan dan      29 May 30 19:38 objdump -> arm-unknown-linux-gnu-objdump
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dan dan      24 May 30 19:38 ld -> arm-unknown-linux-gnu-ld
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dan dan      26 May 30 19:38 gcov -> arm-unknown-linux-gnu-gcov
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dan dan      31 May 30 19:38 gcc-4.0.1 -> arm-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-4.0.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dan dan      25 May 30 19:38 gcc -> arm-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dan dan      27 May 30 19:38 gprof -> arm-unknown-linux-gnu-gprof
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dan dan      28 May 30 19:38 gccbug -> arm-unknown-linux-gnu-gccbug
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dan dan      25 May 30 19:38 g++ -> arm-unknown-linux-gnu-g++
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dan dan      25 May 30 19:38 c++ -> arm-unknown-linux-gnu-c++
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dan dan      29 May 30 19:38 strings -> arm-unknown-linux-gnu-strings
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dan dan      29 May 30 19:38 c++filt -> arm-unknown-linux-gnu-c++filt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dan dan      26 May 30 19:38 size -> arm-unknown-linux-gnu-size
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dan dan      25 May 30 19:38 cpp -> arm-unknown-linux-gnu-cpp
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dan dan      29 May 30 19:38 readelf -> arm-unknown-linux-gnu-readelf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dan dan      31 May 30 19:38 addr2line -> arm-unknown-linux-gnu-addr2line
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dan dan      29 May 30 19:38 objcopy -> arm-unknown-linux-gnu-objcopy
```

So I can execute the symbolic link in that directory:

```
dan@Linux-Desktop:~/dev/arm/gcc-4.0.1-glibc-2.3.5/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/bin$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

but when I try to execute the sym link anywhere else:

```
dan@Linux-Desktop:~/dev/arm/gcc-4.0.1-glibc-2.3.5/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/bin$ cd ..
dan@Linux-Desktop:~/dev/arm/gcc-4.0.1-glibc-2.3.5/arm-unknown-linux-gnu$ bin/gcc --version
bash: bin/gcc: No such file or directory
```

Just for fun, I created a bash script in the bin directory:

```
dan@Linux-Desktop:~/dev/arm/gcc-4.0.1-glibc-2.3.5/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/bin$ echo "gcc --version" > check.sh
dan@Linux-Desktop:~/dev/arm/gcc-4.0.1-glibc-2.3.5/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/bin$ chmod +x check.sh
dan@Linux-Desktop:~/dev/arm/gcc-4.0.1-glibc-2.3.5/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/bin$ ./check.sh
gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

dan@Linux-Desktop:~/dev/arm/gcc-4.0.1-glibc-2.3.5/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/bin$ cd ..
dan@Linux-Desktop:~/dev/arm/gcc-4.0.1-glibc-2.3.5/arm-unknown-linux-gnu$ bin/check.sh
gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

and it works fine from any other directory.

then I thought it was conflicting with the other gcc and changed the link name to gcc2:

```
dan@Linux-Desktop:~$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
dan@Linux-Desktop:~$ which gcc2
/home/dan/dev/arm/gcc-4.0.1-glibc-2.3.5/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/gcc2
dan@Linux-Desktop:~$ gcc2 --version
bash: /home/dan/dev/arm/gcc-4.0.1-glibc-2.3.5/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/gcc2: No such file or directory
```

I can't even run the explicit exe from any other directory:

```
dan@Linux-Desktop:~$ cat testd.sh
ls -ltr /home/dan/dev/arm/gcc-4.0.1-glibc-2.3.5/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc
/home/dan/dev/arm/gcc-4.0.1-glibc-2.3.5/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc --version
dan@Linux-Desktop:~$ ./testd.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 2 dan dan 201417 May 30 16:44 /home/dan/dev/arm/gcc-4.0.1-glibc-2.3.5/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc
./testd.sh: line 2: /home/dan/dev/arm/gcc-4.0.1-glibc-2.3.5/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc: No such file or directory
dan@Linux-Desktop:~$
```

This is my `PATH`:

```
dan@Linux-Desktop:~$ printenv PATH
/home/dan/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/dan/java/jdk-11.0.11+9/bin:/home/dan/dev/arm/gcc-4.0.1-glibc-2.3.5/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/bin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hypothesis: the executable you're trying to run is [for an incompatible architecture](https://superuser.com/a/194256/432690)

> The program was compiled for an incompatible architecture, resulting in a non-executable program. The error message stating "does not exist" instead of "invalid executable" is just a very misleading message.

or [it misses required libraries](https://superuser.com/a/344584/432690).

In particular:

1. When in the directory, `gcc --version` runs `gcc` *from somewhere else* in your `PATH`, not the file (symlink) present in the directory. It's probably `/usr/bin/gcc`. The title is "can't execute symbolic links to exes unless in the directory where the links are located" but the "unless" part is a misinterpretation. In the directory you did not run the symlink. `./gcc --version` would run it.
2. When in the parent directory, `bin/gcc --version` tries to run the symlink and it points to `arm-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc` which triggers the misleading error per the hypothesis.
3. The shell script `check.sh` worked either way because the first place to find it via your `PATH` was the directory and the problem does not apply to running the script itself. Note `gcc` inside the script was located via `PATH` like in (1) and it worked like in (1).
4. The link named `gcc2` never works because there is no `gcc2` in directories earlier in the `PATH`. The only `gcc2` is the symlink in the directory and it points to the problematic executable.
5. The script `testd.sh` explicitly calls `arm-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc` by its full path and the problem occurs.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I just ran the file command on one of the exe's and it's for 32-bit.